# библиотека BeautifulSoup рандомный парсинг

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, bs4

Сделал маленький парсер для телеграм бота. Парсинг последнюю новость с сайта https://lifehacker.ru/ Возможно ли сделать так, что бы он парсил рандомную новость, а не только первую?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'https://lifehacker.ru/'


source = requests.get(url)
main_text = source.text
soup = BS(main_text)

link = soup.find('a', {'class': 'ab-link'}).get('href')
```

Comment: Находите все, выбираете их всех случайную.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Я так понимаю должен прописать findAll? Но как находить случайную, не подскажите куда копать?)

Comment: module `random`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import random

url = 'https://lifehacker.ru/'


source = requests.get(url)
main_text = source.text
soup = BS(main_text,'lxml')

links = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'ab-link'})
print(random.choice(links).get("href"))
```

Comment: Примите пожалуйста ответ, если он вам помог.

Comment: Здравствуйте Виктор. Ответ принял, он находит и принтует рандомную ссылку в терминале. Но при попытке вывести ссылку в телеграм боте, выдаёт ошибку по типу "Сервер вернул слишком большой HTTP". Похоже я не правильно использую код?)

Comment: Надо брать часть всех новостей , но как это реализовать?Возможно у части новостей есть классы которых нет у других?

Comment: Возможно) Ладно, спасибо за помощь) Думаю есть метод по типу findAll, только вместо всего, он брал к примеру первые 20 ссылок?)

Comment: Может так: `links = [a.get("href") for a in soup.findAll("a", {"class":"ab-link"})]`?

Comment: Принимает только последнюю новость с Сайта)

Comment: У меня вроде работает как должно...
Вот что я получил за три запуска:
https://lifehacker.ru/vneshnij-ssd-dlya-uskoreniya-mac/,

https://lifehacker.ru/dorogoj-smartfon-ne-nuzhen/,

https://lifehacker.ru/muzhskie-zimnie-kurtki-aliexpress/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101142/discussion-between-sherlock-and-victor).